# Creating new Blob from MediaRecorder blob parts results in empty Blob

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm experiencing a very strange behaviour from the `new Blob` constructor. I have an array of Blobs returned by the MediaRecorder:

[image: blobs from MediaRecorder]

Now, I cannot seem to do anything with this blob from within my code. Running `new Blob(audioChunks)` in my code results in an empty array being outputted, yet running the same command in the console creates a new Blob correctly! Here's the full method:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(stream => {
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        mediaRecorder.start();

        const audioChunks = [];
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
          audioChunks.push(event.data);
        });

        sleep(1000).then(r => {
          mediaRecorder.stop();
          console.log(audioChunks) // Show the audioChunks
          console.log(new Blob(audioChunks)) // Show the failed blob
          let audio = new File(new Blob(audioChunks), `${name}.webm`, {
            type: "audio/webm;codecs=opus"
          });
          global.addTrack("filename", audio, id);
          console.log(audioChunks)
        });
      });
```

When I click on the button that triggers this, I get the following console output:

[image: console output with errors]

This is built as a method in Vue.js, but not sure if that really makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 1):

One problem you could be running into is you aren't setting the timeslice in mediaRecorder.start(), so your sleep timeout is firing before you get any data. (this is only a problem for such a short test)

To set a smaller timeslice (100ms, for example):

```
mediaRecorder.start(100);
```

There are some other problems you'll run into, but this answers your initial question.

FYI, you can just pass the array of blobs to new File(), it was barfing on a blob of blobs for me.  I changed it to this and it succeeds:

```
let audio = new File(audioChunks, `${name}.webm`, {
    type: "audio/webm;codecs=opus"
});
```

I don't know the intended purpose of this line:

```
global.addTrack("filename", audio, id);
```

I'm getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined' here.  What's this for?

Comment: appreciate the response, but that's not correct in the first instance. I am getting data, as you can see by the blob being returned that contains bytes. The problem is turning that blob into bytes gives me an empty blob

Comment: Must be platform-dependent.  That was the first issue I ran into.  AudioChunks is already an array of Blogs.  Why do you think you need to make a new Blob out of it?